# GoogleのAppsheetはBusiness Standardだと社内で無料でデプロイできる？

Tags: google-spreadsheet, google-cloud-platform

かなり初歩的な質問で恐縮です・・・

今朝、Googleからメールが来ていて

> Good news! As a valued Google Workspace customer, your organization
> now has access to AppSheet Core edition, included at no additional
> cost with your current Workspace plan.

とありました。
社内用にアプリを作成してデプロイしたいです。
１０人以上で利用する場合でも追加料金なしでアプリを利用することができますか？
もしくは引き続きprototypeでの運用をしないと無料で使うことはできないのでしょうか？
Business Standardを契約しています。

Comment: キーワードで検索しただけですが、例えば以下の記事は参考になりますか？ [AppSheet Core がデフォルトで含まれるGoogle Workspace Editionが拡大](https://appsheet-apps.jp/appsheet/appsheet-core-google-workspace/)